# Mongo DB to Codeigniter Implementation

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter

I am newbie in mongo db.  I want to translate a mongo db code to codeigniter understandable format.

```
db.demo.find({}, {
    "person": 1
});
```

Comment: you need to use mongodb library https://github.com/vesparny/cimongo-codeigniter-mongodb-library

Answer (score 2):

Here are the relevant code files from my project.

**config/mongo.php**

```
$config['mongo_server'] = null;
$config['mongo_dbname'] = 'mydb';
libraries/Mongo.php

class CI_Mongo extends Mongo
{
    var $db;

    function CI_Mongo()
    {   
        // Fetch CodeIgniter instance
        $ci = get_instance();
        // Load Mongo configuration file
        $ci->load->config('mongo');

        // Fetch Mongo server and database configuration
        $server = $ci->config->item('mongo_server');
        $dbname = $ci->config->item('mongo_dbname');

        // Initialise Mongo
        if ($server)
        {
            parent::__construct($server);
        }
        else
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        $this->db = $this->$dbname;
    }
}
```

**And a sample controller**

**controllers/posts.php**

```
class Posts extends Controller
{
    function Posts()
    {
        parent::Controller();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $posts = $this->mongo->db->posts->find();

        foreach ($posts as $id => $post)
        {
            var_dump($id);
            var_dump($post);
        }
    }

    function create()
    {
        $post = array('title' => 'Test post');
        $this->mongo->db->posts->insert($post);
        var_dump($post);
    }
}
```